# Error: 1327 invalid drive, but need the networked versions of favourites

Tags: windows, virtualbox, manjaro, naturallyspeaking

So I run Manjaro for personal use but also have to use a windows VM (in virtual box version: 5.2.18 r123745, Qt5.11.1). My work/school has provided me with 5TB of OneDrive storage.

I have set up a sync service on my Linux desktop and set the home folders shown in dolphin to match, I have also shared this folder with the VM and set its documents/downloads etc to match the drive. This means that all my stuff easily synced between the two machines without having to sync twice (upload and download each time).

However, VirtualBox maps shared drives as network drives, in my case E:/.

I am now trying to install a piece of software in particular 'Dragon Naturally Speaking pro'. But after extracting all the files the installer gives Error: 1327.

How do I save this but keep the favourites/quick access folders pointing to the shared folder?

P.S
I have completely disabled all firewalls etc on the VM and kept the defaults on the host

Host Details:

`uname -a --> Linux tasty-laptop 4.14.71-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 20 05:29:20 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Guest Details:

`Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 1803
Installed on: 29/09/2018
OS build: 17134.1`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.  What version?  The last version of Dragon NaturallySpeaking Pro was 13, but  I can't say whether it supports Win 10.  The product version has been upgraded twice and is now known as Dragon Professional Individual (DPI or DPG for the Group editon), and is version 15.3.  DPI14 and 15.3 support Win 10.

But, afaik, no version of Dragon can be installed on anything other than the Win system drive (usually C:) and that includes your virtual box, however, you will find options to move the user profile location and other support folders to your network storage (E:) so there should be no worries (as Dragon binaries, executables and libraries have no meaning outside the Win OS anyway).

So install Dragon to the default system drive in virtual box, but use the E; drive for profile storage, roaming storage (only in DPG, that is, the Group edition), log file locations, auto-transcribe folders, data distribution folders, etc. and have at it.

EDIT:  Btw, let us know if you get it up and how the audio was configured from host (exclusive, non-exclusive?) and in the vb (what was the audio driver, and what does Dragon regard as the source?)

Hth,